# Noob mystified by NSMutable array's behaviour

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm a noob, trying to get my head around using XCode to put together a very simple interface for a very simple Mac app.

I've stripped my app down as much as possible to illustrate the snag I've hit.

My current interface consists of a single button.

In my AppController.h file I have the following:

```
    @interface AppController : NSObject 
    {
        NSMutableArray *ages;
        int price;
        NSString *culler;
    }
    -(IBAction) handleButtonClick: (NSButton*)sender;

    @end
```

and in my AppController.m file, I use my awakeFromNib method to set initial values:

```
    -(void)awakeFromNib
    {
        ages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
        [ages addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 10]];
        [ages addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 21]];

        price = 45;

        culler = [NSString stringWithString: @"bright green"];

        NSLog(@"waking up from nib, ages contains %i objects",[ages count]);
        NSLog(@"they are ...");
        for(int i = 0; i<[ages count]; i++)
        {
                NSLog(@"%i", [[ages objectAtIndex: i] integerValue]);
        }   

        NSLog(@"waking up from nib, the current price is %i", price);   
        NSLog(@"waking up from nib, the color is %@", culler);      

    }
```

That all seems to work fine, and I get the log messages I'm expecting.

But in my method for handling a click on my single button, I have the following:

```
-(void) handleButtonClick: (NSButton*) sender
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked the button");
    NSLog(@"after clicking the button, the current price is %i", price);
    NSLog(@"after clicking the button, the color is %@", culler);   

    NSLog(@"after clicking the button, ages contains %i objects",[ages count]);
    NSLog(@"they are ...");
    for(int i = 0; i<[ages count]; i++)
    {
            NSLog(@"%i", [[ages objectAtIndex: i] integerValue]);
    }   

}
```

When I click on the button, I get log messages telling me that 'culler' and 'prices' contain exactly what I expect (= exactly the values I gave them in 'awakeFromNib') but the program then spits out a "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”" message and the beach ball puts in an appearance, as if it doesn't like me referring to my 'ages' array.

There's obviously something fundamental that I'm not understanding here. 
I can refer to my int and my NSString but not refer to my NSMutableArray?

I'm baffled.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thank You for reading this.

Comment: why not copy code here instead of using screenshots?

Comment: You're right - I should have used code. New to the forum - got confused with the options available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're initializing your array with `arrayWithObjects`. Note this methods return an *autoreleased* object, that's probably not valid after your `awakeFromNib` ends.

Either add a `retain` message:

```
ages = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil] retain];
```

Or use a method that won't return an *autoreleased* object, such as the default `alloc` and `init` way:

```
ages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

And be sure to read the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks for taking the time to help a noob. Much appreciated. Works fine now.

Comment: Glad that works Sam, and welcome to StackOverflow! Also, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking in the check mark bellow the vote count. This way you may also help future readers by identifying the solution to the problem.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, the beach ball occurs because of exactly this. Make good memory management habits early on and you will be a happy programmer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you didn't retain `ages`.  So it's going "poof" when the code "comes up for air" in the UI presentation.

You need to study up on storage management in Objective-C.

Comment: Thank You. Storage management just moved to the top of my 'things to study' list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain your array when you create it otherwise it'll get destroyed at the end of the current event loop.  You can also use the [[alloc] init] style creation which doesn't necessarily require a retain.